# CS50 Mario More Sentimental Python - Not Printing Rows

Tags: python, cs50

I am attempting to write the CS50 Mario More Sentimental (Python) and I am running across some issues. The code is not performing correctly and is generating some issues as listed below:

```
Results for cs50/problems/2020/x/sentimental/mario/more generated by check50 v3.1.2
:) mario.py exists.
:) rejects a height of -1
:) rejects a height of 0
:( handles a height of 1 correctly
    expected ""#  #"", not ""
:( handles a height of 2 correctly
    expected "" #  #"\n"##  ...", not ""
:( handles a height of 8 correctly
    expected ""       #  #"\...", not ""
:( rejects a height of 9, and then accepts a height of 2
    expected program to reject input, but it did not
:) rejects a non-numeric height of "foo" 
:) rejects a non-numeric height of "" 
To see the results in your browser go to https://submit.cs50.io/check50/74938be07d19fd3664e32b052c21717012088526
```

I am not understanding why it will not display the blocks now...

```
# make sure there is valid input
while True:
    try:
        # ask for input
        height = int(input("Height: "))

        # make sure height is greater than 0 and less than or equal to 8
        if height >= 1 and height <= 8:
            break

        # iterate through height
        for counter in range(height):
            print(" " * (height - 1 - counter), end="")
            print("#" * (counter + 1), end="")
            print(" " * 2, end="")
            print("#" * (counter + 1), end="")
            print(end="\n")

    # display error message is value entered is below or above 1 and 8
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a number between 1 and 8. ", end="\n")
```

Comment: I don't understand what your question is (which may have to do with that you didn't ask one). Can you please explain what the problem is with the code you have shown? What did you expect to happen and how is what actually happens different?

Comment: I've edited my original post to define what I am seeing as an issue.

Comment: in your except block you have the code break in your if h >= 0 whereas in your try block you set c to 0: the problem may be that you meant to break in the try block

Comment: I've edited my try and exception blocks and now I am making some progress, however, the pyramid is still not building...

Comment: Try moving the for loop out of the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why we need while loop at all. Try taking height input from user without while loop and check if h>=1 & h<=8, if yes: run your for loop else: print error message & exit()

```
height = int(input("Height: "))
if height >= 1 and height <= 8:
        for counter in range(height):
            print(" " * (height - 1 - counter), end="")
            print("#" * (counter + 1), end="")
            print(" " * 2, end="")
            print("#" * (counter + 1), end="")
            print(end="\n")
else:
 print("Please enter height between 1 and 8")
 exit()
```